# position: absolute inside position: relative causes content to overlap

Tags: css, position

I have a `main` element I have set to `position: relative`. This contains two `div`s that I then apply `position: absolute` on. This then causes the header and footer that sandwich the `main` element to then bump up against each other. How can I stop this?

Using floats and clearing the footer seems to give the two column layout I want. But I'm not sure how “sturdy” a solution that is and what'll happen on IE6/7.

Code on [codepen](http://codepen.io/jonnybarnes/pen/lgqdr).

Comment: Once you make an element `absolute`, it's removed from normal document flow calculations and it becomes your job to prevent the collisions/overlaps.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: I want the `main` to contain a two column layout. I know the widths but not the heights of the two `div`s. So I thought if I could used `position: absolute` to position the two columns(divs). But then I still want the footer to appear at the bottom. Which it currently isn't doing, as explained by Marc B's comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you elements in `main` are absolutely positioned, so `main`'s height computes to zero, so the bottom edge of the header is next to the top edge of the footer.  If you add a height to `main` you will open up space between the header and footer.

Given the following HTML:

```
<header>Header</header>
<main>
  <div id="text">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>Footer</p>
</footer>
```

You can realize a two-column layout using floats as shown in the following CSS:

```css
main {
position: relative;
height: auto;
overflow: auto;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

#text {
float: left;
width: 500px
}

#links {
float: left;
width: 400px;
}
```

You need to set `overflow: auto` on your `main` container to contain the floats (equivalent to clearing them).

Also, make sure that the widths of the floated element are not too wide or else they will wrap to a 2nd line if the screen size is too narrow.

See demo at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGsjd

**Footnote: Using overflow:auto versus clear:both**

I tend to use `overflow: auto` but in some cases the the `clear` property is what is needed.  At some point, read up about "block formatting contexts" at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting The reasons to pick one approach over the other are a bit subtle and the choice depends on the details of the layout that you are trying to achieve, how it behaves in a responsive manner and so on.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how tall the main element will be, so I don;t know how much height to add to the `main`.

Comment: Which would you recommend? `clear: both` on footer, or `overflow: auto` on the main? They both seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try `overflow: auto` for now and see how things go.